Imgui text box rendered inside QtVulkanWindowRenderer cannot use Windows IME
I made a Qt desktop app that has a QVulkanWindowRenderer and made a text box appear inside the Vulkan renderer window using Imgui. I can type into it as expected in English but when I try to switch languages in the Windows taskbar to Korean, the language doesn't change to Korean in the taskbar if the cursor is focused on the Imgui text field inside the Vulkan renderer and the characters appear only appear in English. In any other text field (text editor, browser, even Qt text fields that aren't in the Vulkan renderer) changing the language in the task bar correctly works and I can type in Korean or at the very least the characters will show up as ?????? which means the Windows ime input is being received correctly but the program doesn't have the necessary fonts to display them.
I am receiving the inputs using an eventFilter.
class MyVulkanRenderer : public QObject, public QVulkanWindowRenderer {
public:
    MyVulkanRenderer(QVulkanWindow* w) : m_window(w) {
        m_window->installEventFilter(this);
    }
 }

In the overridden eventFilter function I have code like this that picks up input events and maps it to imgui context.
 case QEvent::KeyPress:
 case QEvent::KeyRelease: {
            const bool down = event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress;
            QKeyEvent* ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

            if (down)
            {
                key_text.append(ke->text());
                if (!key_text.isEmpty()) {
                    for (const QChar& c : key_text) {
                        ImWchar u = c.unicode();
                        if (u)
                            io.AddInputCharacter(u);
                    }
                    key_text.clear();
                }
            }

            io.AddKeyEvent(qtKeyToImguiKey(Qt::Key(ke->key())), down);

I think the problem is because all the input events go through QtVulkanWindowRenderer and the inputs need to be mapped to imgui functions for them to have any effect, like here when I mapped the key press event from Qt to imgui. What I don't understand is how to map the event(if there is one) when the language button in the Windows taskbar which uses Windows ime is clicked by the user. I feel like the button is not changing when clicked because the focus is on the QVulkanWindowRenderer and there are no events being fired.

language switching

Any help or tips on how to work this out is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Right now you're just "forwarding" key events, you should probably manage focus events too, ensuring that the text box knows that when it actually gets or loses focus. I also suspect that you'd need to consider the focusObject related function and signal, and probably check the Qt docs related to input methods.

You'll probably need to customize the window event handler for whatever thread is currently receiving the input messages.  That means digging into the platform specific extensions for Qt though. This question and corresponding answer should be illustrative in what you need to do to get IME working.
Alternatively a cursory search of IME support for Qt reveals this article on support input methods. Of course one issue with this is that if you're rendering content inside a graphics context, but the IME is popping up some native window to assist with the character selection, you might have to jump through some hoops to map the location of the ImGUI control to the appropriate coordinate system for the native window.  I had to deal with this problem quite a bit when I was attempting to render web pages into render context, but had to support forms that might have dropdowns that rely on native window widgets.
